# How do you create a nuget package in a TFS post build script?

Tags: powershell, tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to package and publish a library with nuget from a TFS post build script. It seems that TFS build doesn't use the standard project output paths, so it's making things complicated. All I want to do is build the project (which it does) and then pack and publish with nuget.

Here's my script. It runs just fine on my local machine.

```
param([string]$project, [string]$version)

if (-not $project)
{
  Write-Error ("The project parameter is required.")
  exit 1
}

if (-not $version)
{
  $version = $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
}

if (-not $version)
{
  Write-Error ("Either the version parameter or the TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER environment variable is required.")
  exit 1
}

$projectFile = "$project\$project.csproj"
$packageFile = "$project.$version.nupkg"
$nugetPath = ".nuget\NuGet.exe"

if ($Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)
{
  # relative paths won't work on the build server
  $projectFile = "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\$projectFile"
  $packageFile = "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\$packageFile"

  $nugetPath = "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\$nugetPath"
}
else
{
  $nugetPath = ".\$nugetPath"
}

Write-Host ("packing $projectFile...")
& $nugetPath pack "$projectFile" -Version $version -Symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

And here's the error I'm getting.

```
& : The term '.\.nuget\NuGet.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\a\src\project\.build\PublishPackage.ps1:85 char:3
+ & $nugetPath pack "$projectFile" -Version $version -Symbols -IncludeReferencedPr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (.\.nuget\NuGet.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I simplified the script so the line number won't match, but you can see that it's the last line that's causing the error. I'm using Visual Studio Online with a hosted build controller.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the standard mechanism?

1. Right click on your solution and "Enable  Nuget Package Restore"
   This will create a folder that contains a NuGet.targets file
2. Open than file and set to true the Property BuildPackage

```
      <!-- Property that enables building a package from a project -->
      <BuildPackage Condition=" '$(BuildPackage)' == '' ">true</BuildPackage>
```

3. Edit each project in your solution you want to produce a nuget package from

   - Right click on the project -> "Unload Project"
   - Right click on the project again and "Edit [NameofYourProject]"
   - Set BuildPackage to true by adding the following to the first PropertyGroup

```
    
    <BuildPackage>true</BuildPackage>
```

4. Save the file and Reload the project
5. Commit your changes queue a new build and you should see your package within the build outcome.

This will basically use the project file (for C# the .csproj) to create your package

---

If you need more control over your package creation you could include in you project a .nuspec file
Where you can specify more metadata attributes such as: dependencies,  tags, title,  owners, etc

or even you could use parameters like

```
    <version>$version$</version>
```

to synchronize the nuget package version with the actual assembly version.

If you need to specify the OutDir on the nuget build command for the build server modify the NuGet.targets file `BuildCommand` definition as  follow.

```
<BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutDir=$(OutDir)" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) -OutputDirectory "$(PackageOutputDir)" -symbols</BuildCommand>
```

Comment: I didn't even know that was in `NuGet.targets`. Is this documented?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet. I moved most of my builds to Build preview (non-xaml).